# How many arrows can an archer carry/bring with him?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, ammunition

What would be a realistic number of arrows for an archer to have/carry/bring with him? Dozens or hundreds?

Comment: A bit of context would help greatly here (in other words: why do you want to know?). I suspect the answer will be considerably different between adventurer, hunter out for a day trip, and guard on an extended journey (just to name a few variables).

Comment: Also, are you looking for how many the archer can *transport*?  Or how many he can *access*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we're talking about how many arrows an archer can carry, I'd say it's limited only by carrying capacity - if you want to fill your backpack up with arrows, good for you.

I suspect what you want is: how many arrows can an archer fire in one encounter? (Keeping in mind that getting an arrow from a quiver is essentially "free", as opposed to retrieving something from a pack). At that point, I'd probably rule you're limited to two quivers - one on the hip, one on the back. If you don't have a backpack, I'd probably let you have a third (on the opposite shoulder). Once you've exhausted those, then I'd say you'd have to take actions to retrieve another quiver from your pack.

Comment: Yes Allen, your suspect is right. I know that if you follow the rules, what one can carry is only limited by the carrying capacity. However I can't imagine an archer full of quivers full of arrows still having the same effectivness in moving with some dexterity and firing with the same precision... More general I think that carrying capacity(and the deriving encumbrance) should be treadted differently in combat... However, for me one is right and two still acceptable :)

Comment: @Francesco - Keep in mind that 3.5 only cares about encumbrance as weight, not bulk. (As a proof, consider how astoundingly awkward it would be to carry around even a single 10-foot pole indoors.)

Answer (score 12):

Going by the pathfinder weapon stats [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons), a quiver contains 20 arrows and weighs 3 pounds. Therefore, you should be able to bring as many as you can carry, which depends on your carrying capacity and method of transportation.

Edit: A PC archer, by third level, can probably bring enough arrows with them (using a mount, a strong friend, a ship, or similar for what's to bulky for themselves) and has enough gold that it is not worth tracking how many arrows they expend in most cases.

Answer (score 12):

Having carried 10 arrows per quiver with 1.5" diameter heads, and three quivers usably, doing SCA wars... and knowing that real combat arrows are under 1/2" diameter, one could reasonably shove 30+ arrows per quiver. Note that the second and third quiver was not draw-ready, but was where I could re-sling it on the field to draw from.

So, in theory, I'd say probably 120-160. But you're not going to want more than 30 in a quiver, and that quiver is several inches in diameter. It's not that heavy, but it is bulky.

Answer (score 4):

I would say 20 per quiver. I did not find something specific in the rules but reading the description of [Efficient Quiver](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/efficient-quiver) it seems that a normal quiver contains 20 arrows:

> This Appears to be a typical arrow container capable of holding about
>   20 Arrows. It has three distinct portions, each with a nondimensional
>   space allowing it to store far more than would normally be possible.
>   The first and smallest one can contain up to 60 objects of the same
>   general size and shape as an arrow. 
>   [...]

I would then say that if you have a backpack you can carry no more than one quiver

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @sebsmith and @Matteo, the rule is 20 arrows per standard quiver.  When you play, you should also consider the logistics of a quiver's size, not just its weight.  In real life practicality, a typical adventurer can really only carry one or two quivers at a time, making a practical limit of 20-40 arrows carried without using a mount or a henchman.

There are magical helpers as well, such as the Efficient Quiver that @Matteo mentioned (known as a Quiver of Elhonna in DnD editions), which can boost the capacity 3x or more.

Though rules vary or don't exist in the various rule-sets, our group typically will play a rule that 50% of arrows that don't hit their intended target are recoverable/reusable, which tends to lessen a little bit the problems associated with only being able to carry a finite number of arrows.  Also, being able to scavenge arrows from defeated enemies helps as well.